# Add active class to anchor based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add and active class to anchor based on URL but add active class to all anchor element

```
<div class="year-wrapper">
  <a href="/articles/2017" class="year">2017</a>
  <a href="/articles/2016" class="year">2016</a>
  <a href="/articles/2015" class="year">2015</a>
  <a href="/articles/2014" class="year">2014</a>
  <a href="/articles/2013" class="year">2013</a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdpPdz

Let us say my url is `http://localhost:49660/articles/2014` then it should add active class to anchor element with `2014` while it adds active class to all items. tried few different example withour success.

```
//http://localhost:49660/articles/2014
 $(function () {
    $('.year-wrapper a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
    //$('.year-wrapper a[href^="articles/2014"').addClass('active');

});
```

```
.year-wrapper { width:50%; padding:20px; background:#f5f5f5; color:black; margin:10% auto;}
.year{margin:10px; padding:10px; background:green;}
.active{background:yellow;}
```

I also tried:

```
$('.year-wrapper > a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: `location.pathname.split("/")[1]` are your sure it 1 ?

Comment: Try `location.href.split("/").pop()` @Learning

Comment: @TemaniAfif, you have a point  let me see what [1] gets

Comment: @Varun, I had alaredy tried example with .pop which doesnt add any active class

Comment: @Learning: what do you get on the console if you type: `location.pathname` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

In JS,

```
$('.year-wrapper a[href$="'+(location.href.split("/").pop())+'"]').addClass("active");
```

Dont try it in codepen,there the URL Changes.
But this code worked and changed the last one to yellow when i tried.
Notice the `$` instead of `^`.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use `location.pathname`.

When URL is `http://localhost:49660/articles/2014`, `location.pathname` will be `/articles/2014`, So `$('.year-wrapper a[href^="' + location.pathname + '"]')` can indicates year 2014 link.